# A problem with find and grep

Tags: bash, find, grep, alias

I have defined the following alias in `~/.bashrc`:

```
 alias fg='find . -name $1 | xargs grep --color $2'
```

in order to write

```
fg "*.txt" " my_text "
```

and find all file that have extension .txt and contain " my_text " but it does not work. Why?

Comment: I think that you cannot pass arguments to an alias. Try converting `fg` to a [function](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) instead.

Comment: I have an alias --> alias ff='find . | xargs grep $1 -sl' which works fine!

Comment: `fg is a shell builtin`, I recommend you chose a different name whether you implement this as an alias or (better still) a function.

Comment: @Narak, I think your second example there is only working by accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works!

```
function fndg()
{
   find . -name "$1" | xargs grep -rn --color "$2"
}
```

Comment: `find` can call grep without xargs invocation, see `-execdir`, but in this case, the called program `grep` can iterate itself.

Comment: xargs will be more efficient, as it will call grep with several filenames at once, instead of one at a time using -exec

Comment: `gnu find` can handle mutliple filenames at once too: `find . -name "$1" -exec grep --color $2 -- {} +` if ended with + instead of ";"

Answer (score 7):

Aliases in bash do not take parameters (as already pointed out), so when you need something like that you can use bash functions (like the one provided by @l0b0).

But what you are trying to achieve here, can be done in a better way by using only grep.

```
grep -r --color --include="*.txt" " my_text " ./
```

BTW, `fg` is a shell built in command, an important one. You should avoid using it as a name for aliases or functions.

EDIT: in a function

```
$ ffg() { rgrep --color --include="$1" "$2" ./; }
$ ffg "*.txt" " my_text "
```

Comment: This assumes GNU `grep`, of course.

Answer (score 3):

`find ./ -name "$1" -exec grep -l "$2" {} \;` should do the trick.

Comment: $i should be $1, and $1 and $2 should be quoted to allow blanks and such in filenames and search-word.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Fixed.